# Schedule class in .NET (C# preferably)?

Tags: c#, .net, class, schedule

Is there a class in .NET that represents a schedule? I am looking for something that can represent a similar schedule to what is in the Windows Task Scheduler or the SQL Server job schedule.

I'm not looking for something to run jobs for me, or do anything other than *represent* a schedule. It just needs to be a class that represents a schedule, and has maybe a few methods for example a method that will compare a datetime to the schedule defined in the class instance and tell me if they are a match.

Comment: Take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I did. It seems too heavy and does more than I want it too. I just want a class that represents a schedule so I can use it in my domain model.

Comment: Have you tried [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) ?

Comment: Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper is just working with the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: something like this may be? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6507/NET-Scheduled-Timer

Comment: This isn't going to be as straight forward as you'd like (i.e. copy and paste), however it's pretty easy to wrap the [CRON scheduling format](http://www.opendedup.org/administrators-guide/5) in a class.